# How to get an specific node in xml with namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm dealing to access an specific node from a XML Document. I realized that this one as a base namespace. Here is the example.

[image]

I'm interested to get the value of the node d:MediaUrl from all descendents node (entry). And I haven't accomplished that.

When I debug the variable iterator 'i', I can see that the XML includes the default namespace again, something like:

```
<entry xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com.ado/..."
```

And also I have to include the another namespace called 'd'.

What can I do to access to that particular nodes?

This is what I have.

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

        string BASE_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

        string d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
        var query = from i in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("entry", BASE_NS))
                    select new Image()
        {
            Url = i.Element(XName.Get("MediaUrl", BASE_NS)).Value
        };

        var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Also, you're select won't work because "MediaURL" is not a child of "Entry", it's a child of "Thumbnail" - `i.Element("content").Element("properties").Element("Thumbnail").Element("MediaUrl")` (namespaces ommitted for brevity).

Comment: Thanks Tim. `i.Element("content")` unfortunately returns null, do I have to include any namespace?

Comment: Do you want all the "MediaUrl" elements from each "Entry", or just one?  There's two in each entry - one under properties, one under Thumbnail.

Comment: To answer your earlier question, for those elements that do not have a namespace prefix (like "content"), you need to use the default namespace (which is the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom"` in the "Feed" element for your example.  To go off my example below, it would be `XNamespace a = "http://www.w3.org/2005/atom";` and then `Descendants(a + "content")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `XNamespace` rather than `XName` (personal preference, mainly - as that's how I've always dealt with namespaces in LINQ to XML).  To me it's less effort to set up the namespaces in advance and then use `Element(NS + "element name") than to use`XName.Get`(though using`XName.Get` is perfectly fine if that's what you want to do.

If you want to get a all the "MediaUrl" elements for each entry, then I'd do something like this:

```
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

var query = (from i in doc.Descendants(d + "MediaUrl")
             select new Image()
             {
                 Url = i.Value
             }).ToList();
```

If you want to get only one of them, then you need to do something a little different, depending on which one you wanted to get.

For the properties MediaUrl:

```
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";

var query = (from i in doc.Descendants(m + "properties")
             select new Image()
             {
                 Url = i.Element(d + "MediaUrl").Value
             }).ToList();
```

For the Thumbnail MediaUrl:

```
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

var query = (from i in doc.Descendants(d + "Thumbnail")
             select new Image()
             {
                 Url = i.Element(d + "MediaUrl").Value
             }).ToList();
```

The key here is to use the namespace in conjunction with the element name in order to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from i in doc.Descendants("{full namespace for prefix d}MediaUrl")
                    select new Image()
        {
            Url = i.Value
        };
```